# STARTING a LOGIN SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have created a login script and it works fine, however, I would like to implement sessions.. I am currently having some trouble with it because my session script is only partially executed. Below is my login script and the test page I'd like it to redirect to, IF the user is logged in.. I want it to display the test page, if not, then I want it to redirect back to the login page (or in this case, the index.php file) and ask the user to login... see code below:

**loginconfig.php:**

```
<?php

// Create a connection

include("dbconfig.php");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) or empty($_POST['password'])) {
        header("location:index.php?msg0=Please complete the required fields.");

    }

    elseif (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM logininformation WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        $login = ($sql) ? mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) : false;

        if (($login) == 0) {

            header("location:index.php?msg1=Invalid username or password, please try again.");

        }
        elseif (($login) > 0) {

            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['username'];

            //header("location:index.php?bid=$username&msg2=You are unable to log in at this time. Website is under construction.");
            header("location:test.php?bid=$sessionwork");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**test.php:**

```
<?php

session_start();

include("dbconfig.php");

$username = $_GET['bid'];
var_dump($_SESSION['login'];


// If user is logged in:

if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])){
    echo "Welcome $username"; 
}

// If user is not logged in:

elseif(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    header("location:index.php?msg4=You need to be logged in!");
}
?>

<html>
<head>
   <title> user page </title>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">
   <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])){
   session_destroy();
?>
<html>
<a href="index.php"> Homepage </a>
</html>
```

Now if you look at the test.php file.. I have sort of told it to check if a user is logged in. But unfortunately, the script only manages to execute the script where it says if the user is not logged in.. redirect to index.php... even if the user enters the correct login credentials and actually logs in. What could be the issue?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I've tried logging in and now its displaying the welcome message, however, if I go to the browser and type "localhost/pmysqli/test.php" it still displays that page.. I want it so it doesn't display that page at all unless the user is logged in.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but if you are using mysqli, use prepared statements. Sql injection is possible with your current code. You also should not store passwords as plain-text in your database.

Comment: When I'm not logged in, the script simply echoes 'Welcome' with the username followed after it. But I don't want it to display that page AT ALL... unless the user is logged in.. and I have changed it to else() .. still no luck :(

Comment: I was meant to say it echoes the welcome message WITHOUT the username followed after it. So when I'm not logged in, it says Welcome but when I am logged in it says Welcome $username... I'll try adding a session_destroy(); and see what it does.

Comment: Yep, I shall try that too.

Comment: I have implemented session_destroy(); which works fine, but my test.php page is still accessible.

Comment: I've changed it to empty() and now it won't log me in at all.. even if I type the correct credentials .. it simply echoes the 'You need to be logged in' message..

Comment: I have included my logout.php file in my question, I have also added the 'var_dump($_SESSION['login']) and it outputs 'string(5)"sarif" Welcome sarif" (this is just test data, don't worry about me pasting my username, its not live data)

Comment: I wrote it as '(if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])){ echo "Welcome $username";' and that actually works, but now it won't destroy the session properly.. if I directly go to test.php via address bar, it still displays 'Welcome sarif'

Comment: I have updated my 'test.php' file in the question - it displays how I'm calling my logout script.

Comment: I have updated test.php and loginconfig.php for your review :)

Comment: @Epodax I have resolved it! - there was an error in my logout.php file .. I shall answer my own question displaying what I did.

Comment: Removing my comments to cleanup the debugging process, glad you got it working.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate your help and support!

Comment: No problem, FYI, you should still look at a3ey's answer and the way of building your if clause, no need to use `elseif` like you are, it's enough to use `else `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I did not have a logout.php file.. therefore I was making the mistake of not destroying my session. The change I had to make to my initial scripting was to create a logout.php file. But when I did, the problem was still present.. in order for it to work.. I made the following changes to the logout.php file.. see below:

**BEFORE:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['login'])){
session_destroy();
?>
<html>
<a href="index.php"> Homepage </a>
</html>
```

**AFTER:**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");
exit();
?>
```

Thank you for those who helped, especially @Epodax for the GREAT support.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this in test.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
 echo "Welcome $_SESSION['login']"; 
}
else{
 header("location:index.php?msg4=You need to be logged in!");
}
```

The same error is repeated in loginconfig.php.

Comment: Referring to my code above, where would you place the "else" part?

Comment: Also $username is not defined in test.php. Try echoing the Session instead.

Comment: $username is defined in test.php, right underneath 'include("dbconfig.php")'